# React-Native Parse ListView onEndReached not working as expected

Tags: parsing, listview, react-native

I'm having an issue with infinite scrolling with the ListView component. This is my list element:

const dataSource = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.getDataSource())

```
<ListView
    onEndReached={this.onEndReached.bind(this)}
    onEndReachedThreshold={5}
    onScroll={this.onScroll.bind(this)}
    dataSource={dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false} />
```

And my onEndReached() code:

```
onEndReached() {
if (this.state.hasScrolled) {
  const dataSource = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.getDataSource())

  this.setState({
    offset: this.state.offset + this.state.limit,
    dataSource
  })
}
```

}

And getDataSource():

```
getDataSource() {
let dataSource = []

if (this.state.messages && this.state.messages.length) {
  this.state.messages.map((message) => {
    dataSource.push(message)
  })
}

return dataSource
```

}

But when I test this code and reach the bottom. It doesn't do anything until my third time triggering onEndReached(), then at that point it sets the offset to a higher than expected number. I tried using a flag such as isLoaded to prevent the onEndReached() from being triggered more than once, but if I do that the list doesn't refresh with the new content.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get past this?

Comment: Note also that if you declare your component methods as ES6 arrows, you don't need to `.bind` everything, e.g.: `onEndReached = () => {/*...*/}` + `<ListView onEndReached={this.onEndReached} />`.